# catch value in razor

Tags: javascript, razor

I try to catch value of input, here's the input:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price_Selling, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price_Selling, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onkeyup = "CheckValue()" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price_Selling, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here's my javaScript:

```
function CheckValue() {
    var pPrc = $('#Price_Selling').val() || 0;        

    alert(pPrc);
}
```

onkeyup just doesn't respond. do I make any mistake? and if it responds, do i get the right value?

Comment: This code looks fine. Do you have any script errors ?  See the working fiddle http://jsbin.com/berapefifi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, it works just fine. I don't know what happen yesterday. And I couldn't remove the question, So I'm sorry for that.